# Telegram-бот отправляет бесконечное количество сообщений при выполнении определенного участка кода

Tags: telegram-bot

Внедряю в бота на питоне с использованием библиотеки pyTelegramBot функцию фильтрации нецензурной лексики. И стоит такая задача: Если пользователь отправляет сообщение содержащее нецензурную брань, бот удаляет сообщение и выводит уведомление о том, что использована нецензурная лексика, а если пользователь пишет что-то другое содержащее текст, то бот отправляет сообщение "не понимаю вас". Проблема заключается в том что после того как пишешь запретное слово (в данном случае поставил "test", бот начинает писать с очень маленьким промежутком времени "не понимаю вас". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    words = ["тест" ]

    phrase = message.text.lower()

    def distance(a, b):
        "Вычисляет расстояние Левенштейна между a и b."
        n, m = len(a), len(b)
        if n > m:
            # Make sure n <= m, to use O(min(n, m)) space
            a, b = b, a
            n, m = m, n

        current_row = range(n + 1)  # Keep current and previous row, not entire matrix
        for i in range(1, m + 1):
            previous_row, current_row = current_row, [i] + [0] * n
            for j in range(1, n + 1):
                add, delete, change = previous_row[j] + 1, current_row[j - 1] + 1, previous_row[j - 1]
                if a[j - 1] != b[i - 1]:
                    change += 1
                current_row[j] = min(add, delete, change)

        return current_row[n]

    d = {'а': ['а', 'a', '@'],
         'б': ['б', '6', 'b'],
         'в': ['в', 'b', 'v'],
         'г': ['г', 'r', 'g'],
         'д': ['д', 'd'],
         'е': ['е', 'e'],
         'ё': ['ё', 'e'],
         'ж': ['ж', 'zh', '*'],
         'з': ['з', '3', 'z'],
         'и': ['и', 'u', 'i'],
         'й': ['й', 'u', 'i'],
         'к': ['к', 'k', 'i{', '|{'],
         'л': ['л', 'l', 'ji'],
         'м': ['м', 'm'],
         'н': ['н', 'h', 'n'],
         'о': ['о', 'o', '0'],
         'п': ['п', 'n', 'p'],
         'р': ['р', 'r', 'p'],
         'с': ['с', 'c', 's'],
         'т': ['т', 'm', 't'],
         'у': ['у', 'y', 'u'],
         'ф': ['ф', 'f'],
         'х': ['х', 'x', 'h', '}{'],
         'ц': ['ц', 'c', 'u,'],
         'ч': ['ч', 'ch'],
         'ш': ['ш', 'sh'],
         'щ': ['щ', 'sch'],
         'ь': ['ь', 'b'],
         'ы': ['ы', 'bi'],
         'ъ': ['ъ'],
         'э': ['э', 'e'],
         'ю': ['ю', 'io'],
         'я': ['я', 'ya']
         }
    for key, value in d.items():
        # Проходимся по каждой букве в значении словаря. То есть по вот этим спискам ['а', 'a', '@'].
        for letter in value:
            # Проходимся по каждой букве в нашей фразе.
            for phr in phrase:
                # Если буква совпадает с буквой в нашем списке.
                if letter == phr:
                    # Заменяем эту букву на ключ словаря.
                    phrase = phrase.replace(phr, key)

    # ПРЕДПОЛАГАЮ ПРОБЛЕМА ГДЕ-ТО В ЭТОМ УЧАСТКЕ КОДА:
    for word in words:
        # Разбиваем слово на части, и проходимся по ним.
        for part in range(len(phrase)):
            # Вот сам наш фрагмент.
            fragment = phrase[part: part + len(word)]
            # Если отличие этого фрагмента меньше или равно 30% этого слова, то считаем, что они равны.
            if distance(fragment, word) <= len(word) * 0.30:
                bot.forward_message(chat_id="@НАЗВАНИЕКАНАЛАУБРАЛ", from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id)
                bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Употребление ненормативной лексики настоятельно не рекомендуется")
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не понимаю вас")
                break
```

Comment: У Вас после выхода из внутреннего цикла продолжают перебираться слова во внешнем цикле и так пока всё не переберётся в words. Поэтому и шлётся пока все words не переберутся

Comment: Как можно исправить данную ситуацию?

Comment: Смотрите ответ и если ОК, то помечайте его как принятый и закрывайте вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
# ПРЕДПОЛАГАЮ ПРОБЛЕМА ГДЕ-ТО В ЭТОМ УЧАСТКЕ КОДА:
flgBad = false
for word in words:
    # Разбиваем слово на части, и проходимся по ним.
    for part in range(len(phrase)):
        # Вот сам наш фрагмент.
        fragment = phrase[part: part + len(word)]
        # Если отличие этого фрагмента меньше или равно 30% этого слова, то считаем, что они равны.
        if distance(fragment, word) <= len(word) * 0.30:
            bot.forward_message(chat_id="@НАЗВАНИЕКАНАЛАУБРАЛ", from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id)
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Употребление ненормативной лексики настоятельно не рекомендуется")
            flgBad = true
            break
    if flgBad == true: break
```

Вариант без flgBad:

```
for word in words:
    # Разбиваем слово на части, и проходимся по ним.
    for part in range(len(phrase)):
        # Вот сам наш фрагмент.
        fragment = phrase[part: part + len(word)]
        # Если отличие этого фрагмента меньше или равно 30% этого слова, то считаем, что они равны.
        if distance(fragment, word) <= len(word) * 0.30:
            bot.forward_message(chat_id="@НАЗВАНИЕКАНАЛАУБРАЛ", from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id)
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Употребление ненормативной лексики настоятельно не рекомендуется")
            break
    else:
        continue

    break
```

Comment: ``if flgBad: break `` - в сравнении нет необходимости. Нет смысла сравнивать true и true чтобы получить true.

Comment: @Эникейщик Это понятно, для визуального понимания сделано

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря комментатору Виктору, удалось решить проблему, рабочий вариант кода выполняющий необходимые задачи выглядит так:

```
 flgBad=False
    for word in words:
        # Разбиваем слово на части, и проходимся по ним.
        for part in range(len(phrase)):
            # Вот сам наш фрагмент.
            fragment = phrase[part: part + len(word)]
            # Если отличие этого фрагмента меньше или равно 30% этого слова, то считаем, что они равны.
            if distance(fragment, word) <= len(word) * 0.30:
                bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Употребление ненормативной лексики настоятельно не рекомендуется")
                flgBad = True
                break
        if flgBad == True: break
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пока что я не понимаю вашей команды")
```